# how to sum the values of texboxes separately rowise and columnwise and display them?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

**All i want to do is calculate rowtotal columntotal for each row and column separately and grandtotal**

```
   <table class="table-bordered table-striped" id="example">
          @*Displays my project list headers from the database*@  

          <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Employee Id
                    </th>
                    <th>Cost Center</th>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                    {
                        <th>@Html.DisplayFor(p => item.ProjectName, new {@class = "projects" })</th>
                    }
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                    {
                        <th>@Html.DisplayFor(p => item.Code.CodeName, new { Style = "width:5em;" })</th>
                    }
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                    {
                        <th>@Html.DisplayFor(p => item.NetworkId)</th>
                    }
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
     @*Displays my employee list from the database*@
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ForecastInfoList.Count(); i++)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Emp1 => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].EmpName)</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].EmpId)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(Emp1 => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].EmpSapId)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Emp1 => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].CostCenter)</td>
                        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours.Count(); j++)
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours[j].EmpId)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours[j].ProjectMasterId)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours[j].Month)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjectHours[j].Hours, new { @class = "Hours", Style = "text-align:left; width:5em;" })  @*displays my textboxes*@
                            </td>
                        }
                        <td>
                            <span class="total_emp_value">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].EmpTotal)  @*displays my vertical total column*@
                            </span>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>
                        Total
                    </th>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ForecastInfoList[0].ProjectHours.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <td>
                            <span class="total_proj_value">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.ForecastInfoList[i].ProjTotal) @*displays my horizontal total column*@
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    }
                    <td>
                        <span class="grandtotal">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ForecastInfoList[0].GrandTotal)
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="button">
        <p><input type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-warning" value="Save" name="Save" /> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script Used

```
   <script>
    $(document).on("input", ".Hours", function () {

        total = 0;
       if ($(this).val() != "") {
           total += parseInt($(this).val());

           $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_emp_value").val($(this).val());
        }
        $(".total_emp_value").html(total);
    });</script>
```

I want to display the sum of individual columns and individual rows into the total column i.e. all the textboxes in that row and all the textboxes in that column should display the total of row and column resp; but when i set my script on .total_emp_value then only the textbox that i recently changed is getting displayed in total total_emp_value

I want to do that separately but since i am new to jquery i am unable to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{
List<string> data = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" }; // Your Model data
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
}

<div>
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in data)
        {
            i++;
            //for () inside loop to break when the count of your object has the last index e.g. i =3 (use break;)
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("name","", new { id = "txtboxRow" + i + "col" + j })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: as per the answer do i need to change my jquery?

Comment: The code above is to generate textbox id with sequence number. After that you have to use JQuery for calculating  rowtotal and columntotal.

Comment: i have the separate id's created with the same logic of yours but now how do i bind sum of individual rows and columns to my total_emp_hrs column

Comment: I am not sue about your requriment. The sum of your rows can be changed after focus out from any textbox. I have updated the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/re7ROFztHZqjUlkzuBBD?p=preview

Comment: The plunker code that you just sent me, does no summation it only displays textboxes

Comment: i have done the changes for first row. Enter any number and press tab (focus out)

Comment: Okay my bad, this is nice but can u add the column addition also same way please?

Comment: also one more thing i would like to highlight how to do addition of the next consecutive row in that total textbox can you show that also please

Comment: Hey @shreyasvispute I have updated the plunker for first column..  You can try to make your  code dynamic for other textboxes which show sum of column/rows. Please check the JQuery documentation for DOM selection for tables for next consecutive row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating a loop with number of rows/columns available. Something like this..

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#value11").val(Number($("#textboxrow1col1").val()) + Number($("#textboxrow1col2").val()));
    });
  </script>
```

#value11, #textboxrow1col1, #textboxrow1col2  - should be dynamic (you can create through razor view)

Here is the plunker for this but not the complete solution:

http://plnkr.co/edit/re7ROFztHZqjUlkzuBBD?p=preview

Comment: i cannot explicitly define #textboxrow1col1... like this because my both rows and columns are generated from a list in the model i don't know how to id each one separately

Comment: @shreyasvispute Please find the below answer. That is done in razor view. You can try to put you model and simulate. Hope it will help.